# How Can I Specify A Minimum Ruby Version in a Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I know that I can specify a Ruby version in a Gemfile like so:

```
ruby '2.0.0'
```

However, instead of setting the exact Ruby version, I'd like to be able to specify a minimum Ruby version so that my scripts remain compatible with new version of Ruby.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Already possible since Bundler 1.12, e.g.

`ruby "~> 2.3.0"`

see here:

https://github.com/bundler/bundler-features/issues/119

Answer (score 15):

You could raise an exception instead:

```
raise 'Ruby should be >2.0' unless RUBY_VERSION.to_f > 2.0
```

Comment: As a Ruby lover, it makes me sad that this is the best way there is to set a minimum Ruby version :(

Comment: @HappyCoder86 As a Python lover myself, I feel your pain :( I wish you could do it like specifying gem's version. `ruby '~>2.0.0'` would be really neat.

Comment: And this is certainly not setting a Ruby version. It is just raising an exception.

Comment: @slindsey3000 that and it also forces the user to either remove it from the gem source or just update ruby if that is possible. If someone put it there, there has to be a reason too right :)