# Syntax for the minimum Ruby version

Tags: ruby, rubygems

The following starts a `Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "~> 2.4.5"
```

This approach is based on the answer [How Can I Specify A Minimum Ruby Version in a Gemfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440712/how-can-i-specify-a-minimum-ruby-version-in-a-gemfile)
:

> Already possible since Bundler 1.12, e.g.
>
> ruby "~> 2.3.0"

I do have the requisite version of *Bunder*:

```
$ bundler -v
Bundler version 1.16.1
```

Yet running that gem gives us:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:create
Your Ruby version is 2.5.1, but your Gemfile specified ~> 2.4.5
```

The `rake` command then fails.   What am I missing?

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? Everything seems to be working as it should.

Comment: The message above is not a warning: it is an error: rake command then fails.

Comment: Yes, that is what should happen.

Comment: Um then what is the answer to my question - i.e. how to allow running the `rake` command with a _newer_ version of ruby?

Comment: `~> x.y.z` means "x.y exactly, and any Z greater than z". If you want to allow 2.4+ but not 3.0, specify `~> 2.4`.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Pls make this an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~> x.y.z` means "x.y exactly, and any Z greater than or equal to z". If you want to allow 2.4+ but not 3.0, specify `~> 2.4`.